# adding more ips to be allowed on iptables rule

Tags: iptables

I have this rule in my iptables

```
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  -- !10.0.0.61            anywhere            tcp dpt:sip
DROP       tcp  -- !c-74-70-17-69.hsd1.co.comcast.net  anywhere            tcp dpt:sip
DROP       tcp  -- !c-74-70-17-69.hsd1.co.comcast.net  anywhere            tcp dpt:http
DROP       tcp  -- !c-74-70-17-69.hsd1.co.comcast.net  anywhere            tcp dpt:https
```

As you can see that its allowing sip, http or https . Now if I add another one using this

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp ! -s 10.0.0.61 --dport 443 -j DROP

to allow 443 for 10.0.0.61 as well, it does not work and shows this

```
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  -- !10.0.0.61            anywhere            tcp dpt:https
DROP       tcp  -- !10.0.0.61            anywhere            tcp dpt:sip
DROP       tcp  -- !c-75-70-17-69.hsd1.co.comcast.net  anywhere            tcp dpt:sip
DROP       tcp  -- !c-75-70-17-69.hsd1.co.comcast.net  anywhere            tcp dpt:http
DROP       tcp  -- !c-75-70-17-69.hsd1.co.comcast.net  anywhere            tcp dpt:https
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are expecting to have happen here.  The rule you add is added.

Comment: As soon as a packet matches a rule that is the end of processing. You should have ALLOW for these addresses (without the not/!) followed by a DROP that matches all addresses for each protocol.

Comment: Every packet matches one or both drop rules for each protocol.

Comment: It would be nice to see your iptables rules. You could execute `iptables-save` and share output.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to describe what you do and what you want. With your rules you DROP all packets that come to `sip,http,https` for all IPs except `10.0.0.61` and `c-75-70-17-69.hsd1.co.comcast.net`

If you want to allow traffic to `sip,http,https` from `10.0.0.61` and `c-75-70-17-69.hsd1.co.comcast.net`, you should add rules:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp -s 10.0.0.61 -m multiport --dports 80,443,5060 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp -s c-75-70-17-69.hsd1.co.comcast.net -m multiport --dports 80,443,5060 -j ACCEPT
```